# Remove 2 consecutive lines meeting a condition

Tags: r

Here is a link of transaction.
this is a scenario of cancelled transaction in a restaurant check.

I want R to check if an item has flag "U", then remove the U and 1 similar item which is not u.

I have marked the items to be removed in Yellow.

```
chk_num dtl_name    Duration    Guest   void_type   Item_ttl
9707    Americano           45  1       18
9707    Americano           45  1       18
9707    Breakfast Tea       45  1       18
9707    Breakfast Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Café Latte          45  1       21
9707    Camomille Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Camomille Tea       45  1       18
9707    Earl Grey Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Earl Grey Tea       45  1       18
9707    Fresh Mint Tea      45  1   U   -18
9707    Fresh Mint Tea      45  1       18
9707    Green Tea           45  1       18
9707    Green Tea           45  1   U   -18
9707    Green Tea           45  1       18
9707    Lemon Tea           45  1       18
9707    Lemon Tea           45  1   U   -18
9707    Orange Juice        45  1       24
9707    Pepper Mint Tea     45  1       18
9707    Pepper Mint Tea     45  1   U   -18
```

[image: Data base Picture]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: don't post pictures. post the result of `dput(YOUR_DATA)`

Comment: why are some orders flagged and "canceled" before beeing "ordered and payed"

Comment: your type the above command into R console. (change YOUR_DATA acc.) and click on EDIT or [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52481587/edit) to edit and update your post.

Comment: @andre Hope this is ok now?

Comment: Better, but still not good enough. I repeat again: "post the result of dput(YOUR_DATA)"

Comment: I think "Earl Grey Tea" should be filtered, too.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
# load the 'data.table'-package & convert 'DF' to a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

# add a rownumber
DF[ , rn := .I][]

# create a subset with only the 'U'-rows and make 'Item_ttl' positive
DF_U <- DF[void_type == "U"][, Item_ttl := Item_ttl * -1][]

# create an index of rownumbers to be removed by:
# - extracting 'rn' from 'DF_U'
# - joining DF_U with DF
#   select only the first matching row in the join
#   and then extract 'rn'
# - concatenate these two vectors into one
ix <- c(DF_U$rn, DF[DF_U, on = .(chk_num,dtl_name,Duration,Guest,Item_ttl), mult = "first"]$rn)
```

Now you can get the desired end result by using:

```
DF[!ix]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    chk_num     dtl_name Duration Guest void_type Item_ttl rn
> 1:    9707    Americano       45     1      <NA>       18  1
> 2:    9707    Americano       45     1      <NA>       18  2
> 3:    9707   Café-Latte       45     1      <NA>       21  5
> 4:    9707    Green-Tea       45     1      <NA>       18 14
> 5:    9707 Orange-Juice       45     1      <NA>       24 17
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

data:

```
df1<-
data.table::fread("chk_num dtl_name Duration Guest void_type Item_ttl
9707    Americano           45  1   NA  18
9707    Americano           45  1   NA  18
9707    Breakfast-Tea       45  1   NA  18
9707    Breakfast-Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Café-Latte          45  1   NA  21
9707    Camomille-Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Camomille-Tea       45  1   NA   18
9707    Earl-Grey-Tea       45  1   U   -18
9707    Earl-Grey-Tea       45  1   NA   18
9707    Fresh-Mint-Tea      45  1   U   -18
9707    Fresh-Mint-Tea      45  1   NA   18
9707    Green-Tea           45  1   NA  18
9707    Green-Tea           45  1   U   -18
9707    Green-Tea           45  1   NA  18
9707    Lemon-Tea           45  1   NA  18
9707    Lemon-Tea           45  1   U   -18
9707    Orange-Juice        45  1   NA  24
9707    Pepper-Mint-Tea     45  1   NA  18
9707    Pepper-Mint-Tea     45  1   U   -18") %>% setDF
```

code:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
        while("U" %in% x$void_type) {
            flagU    <- min(which(x$void_type == "U"))
            delFlagU <- min(which(x$Item_ttl == -x$Item_ttl[flagU]))
            x    <- x[-c(flagU,delFlagU),]
            if(!("U" %in% x$void_type)) {return(x)}

        }
        return(x)
    } 

df1 %>% dplyr::group_by(dtl_name, Duration, Guest) %>% dplyr::do(.,fun1(.))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   dtl_name, Duration, Guest [4]
#  chk_num dtl_name     Duration Guest void_type Item_ttl
#    <int> <chr>           <int> <int> <chr>        <int>
#1    9707 Americano          45     1 <NA>            18
#2    9707 Americano          45     1 <NA>            18
#3    9707 Café-Latte         45     1 <NA>            21
#4    9707 Green-Tea          45     1 <NA>            18
#5    9707 Orange-Juice       45     1 <NA>            24
```

---

please note:

If you have a flag U, but no respective "PAIR", you will be stuck in an infinite while cycle.

You probably want to extend my answer a little bit.

As you tell nothing about your business logic I dont know anything about it. You might adapt the grouping `dplyr::group_by(dtl_name, Duration, Guest)`. Esp with `Duration` I'm not sure.

---

If you are more of a `data.table` guy:

`data.table::setDT(df1)[, fun1(.SD), by = .(dtl_name, Duration, Guest)]`